# Excel persistently reverts formatting of numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel workbook I'm working on, somewhat legacy. It constantly has all of my numbers show up as days of the week. Ok, no biggie, I'll just change the formatting to what I want. Everything's fine.

I'll go and work on some other part of the sheet, come back, and my numbers have turned back into days of the week. This happens the most frequently and repeatably with pivot tables, but I've noticed it occasionally happening elsewhere.

This is driving me up the wall. I'm tempted to restart the sheet from scratch, but I figured I'd see if anyone else has encountered this and knows what's going on.

Thanks

Comment: is there any vba on the workbook?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. It's simply tracking foot traffic at our locations, and type of traffic. Usually when I have VBA on a book, it gives me a warning that there's VBA. Checking the editor has no VBA.

Comment: is there a formula on the cells or on the formatting of the cells which is changing to days of the week

Comment: The vast majority of the sheet is just data, and it's when handling that data it gets changed. If there was a formula going through the day of the week, I'd get it. There are a few formulas here and there, but they're cooperating for the most part.

Comment: A number turns into days of the week? What type of "number" are we talking about? What are the exact specifics. What formula are you using and if you are is it a nested set of formula?

Comment: I wish! Any number - over 700, 2.35, 6,1 - they all get transformed. I haven't seen a negative number get changed yet. It's happened on a new sheet when I was doing a value-only paste as well. However, in that case, there was no reversion when I changed it back. I've noted the reversion occurring primarily with a pivot table, where it just won't "stick" the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Number formatting on Pivot Tables shouldn't be applied directly to the cell. Instead, right click on the cell and go into `Show Values As` > `More Options` > `Number Format` and edit the formatting there.

[image]

[image]